# Чтение из System.in обернутый в BufferedReader

Tags: java, строки

Допустим я хочу  читать из   `BufferedReader` в который подается  консоль `System.in`

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in, charset);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

1) как правильно обозначить конец чтения из консоли, чтобы код пошел дальше (например я ввожу "сlose", или нажимаю enter)

2)из прочитанного нужно получить List слов которые состоят только из слов и цифр

**input:**

```
Мама мыла-мыла-мыла раму!
```

**output**

```
[мама мыла мыла мыла раму]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) обычно просто надо ждать конца потока. В Unix это делается с помощью <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, в DOS/Windows - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Кроме того, если вы на вход программе подадите файл, то конец потока произойдёт, когда кончится файл.

2) Можно воспользоваться регулярным выражением и `split`. Вот пример полной реализации с использованием Java 8:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ReadWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> words = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).lines()
            .flatMap(Pattern.compile("[^\\p{L}\\p{Digit}]+")::splitAsStream)
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(words);
    }
}
```

Регулярное выражение `"[^\\p{L}\\p{Digit}]+"` означает "всё, что не цифры и буквы". Мы используем это в качестве разделителя, получая таким образом всё остальное. Фильтрация нужна, чтобы удалить пустые элементы в начале строк, если строка начинается не с буквы/цифры.

Comment: Что-то  в  консоль пустой лист выводит "[ ]", даже если кодировку убрать. Через сканер без регулярок и стримов тоже ничего не выводит, где -то настройки кодировок сбились видимо В Eclipse File - properties стоит Сp1251(Dafault ingerited from container), Os Windows

Comment: @ketchyn, не подумал про русские буквы, `\W` только английские матчит. Исправил регулярку. Ну и да, скорее всего Cp1251 надо.